# Multiple Assignments in Python dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Lets say I have a list

```
demo  = [['Adam', 'Chicago', 'Male', 'Bears'], ['Brandon', 'Miami', 'Male', 'Dolphins']]
```

I want to make a list of dictionaries using a comprehension that looks like

```
[{'Adam':'Chicago', 'Gender':'Male', 'Location':'Chicago', 'Team':'Bears'},
{'Brandon':'Miami', 'Gender':'Male', 'Location':'Miami', 'Team':'Dolphins'} }
```

It easy enough to assign two starting values to get something like

```
{ s[0]:s[1] for s in demo}
```

but is there a legitimate way to assign multiple values in this comprehension that may look like

```
{ s[0]:s[1],'Gender':s[2], 'Team':s[3] for s in demo}
```

Its such a specific question and the I dont know the terms for searching so Im having a hard time finding it and the above example is giving me a syntax error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionary comprehensions build single dictionaries, not lists of dictionaries.  You say you want to make a list of dictionaries, so use a list comprehension to do that.

```
modified_demo = [{s[0]:s[1],'Gender':s[2], 'Team':s[3]} for s in demo]
```

Comment: Sequence assignment would be much nicer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use zip to turn each entry into a list of key-value pairs:

```
dicts= [dict(zip(('Name','Gender','Location', 'Team'), data) for data in demo]
```

You don't want a 'Name' label, you want to use the name as a label which duplicates location. So, now you need to fix up the dicts:

```
for d in dicts:
    d[d['Name']] = d['Location']
    del d['Name'] # or not, if you can tolerate the extra key
```

Alternatively, you can do this in one step:

```
dicts = [{name:location,'Location':location,'Gender':gender, 'Team':team} for name,location,gender,team in demo]
```

Comment: @JonClements Well, it's the same as your solution, with an extra step.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement just looks odd, are you sure you aren't trying to logically name the fields (which makes far more sense):

```
>>> demo  = [['Adam', 'Chicago', 'Male', 'Bears'], ['Brandon', 'Miami', 'Male', 'Dolphins']]
>>> [dict(zip(['name', 'location', 'gender', 'team'], el)) for el in demo]
[{'gender': 'Male', 'team': 'Bears', 'name': 'Adam', 'location': 'Chicago'}, {'gender': 'Male', 'team': 'Dolphins', 'name': 'Brandon', 'location': 'Miami'}]
```